# smtp host set to localhost in android

Tags: android

After running following code in Android Studio, i am facing issue :-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;   nested exception is:
>   java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

It is using localhost and port 25, instead of assigned host and port.

```
public class GMailSender extends Authenticator {
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

public GMailSender(final String user, final String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;


    //Properties props = new Properties();
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                }
            });


}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("garimabareja28@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("garimabareja28@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String file = "path of file to be attached";
        String fileName = "attachmentName";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `After running following code in Android Studio,` That is impossible. It can only run on your Android device. Or Android emulator. So what are you doing? Edit your post please to give this info.

Comment: I have not done much Android development but it looks like you are redefining your `session` attribute in your constructor instead of simply instantiating it. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties props = new Properties();

```
    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```